# Browser plugin to show if web page is loaded from browser cache or web server

Tags: http, caching, browser, expires-header

I need a chrome or Firefox add on (or other method) to determine when the content I am viewing is loaded from Local browser cache or from the web server.  Preferably breaking down each item as an image may be cached while other content on the same page may be from the server depending on expiry times and other headers.

Comment: You can get all this information from Firebug or Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: I am sure you're right, but where do I look exactly is my question (dev tools has a lot of functionality).

Comment: this is possible using a Chrome extension and the remote.debugging api. You would capture the network requests using this which give you timing, headers, cache details and the actual content itself. These are some of the details you can capture: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.1/network and there are absolutely loads more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geezer68 mentioned, you can use the Chrome Developer tools.  Specifically, use the Javascript Console's Network tab and view the Size field which will specify (from cache) when the browser cache returns the content requested.